# Обработка html кода

Tags: c#

Простая задача, но решить ее обычным .Replace("\n","") почему-то не выходит.

Вообщем, есть html код

```
<html>
<head>
...
<p>Hello World</p>
...
</html>
```

Нужно его склеить в одну строку:

```
<html><head>...<p>Hello World</p>...</html>
```

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 6):

```
.Replace("\n","").Replace("\r","")
```